# Intercepting SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator to prevent migration of certain tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use EF Core 3.0 migrations with a hybrid of an existing tables and new tables built with code first. To prevent the scaffolding of the existing tables I would like to decorate the model class with an attribute (fluently or annotations) so that the migration code generation for those tables is skipped but the model is still built into the DbContext class.

The approach I'm taking is to add the following lines to OnConfiguring

```
optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, SkipMigrator>();
```

And then creating a SkipMigrator with the following code

```
public class SkipMigrator:SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator
{
    public SkipMigrator(
        MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies,
    IMigrationsAnnotationProvider migrationsAnnotations)
    : base(dependencies, migrationsAnnotations){}

    protected override void Generate(
        MigrationOperation operation,
        IModel model,
        MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
    {
        if (operation.FindAnnotation("SkipMigrations")!=null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Skipping table:");
        }
        else
        {
            base.Generate(operation,model,builder);
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed that the `Generate` method was what triggered the creation of the migration code file but it never gets called. Id there a different place I should be intercepting the code generation?

If there a different/simpler way to tell migrations to skip tables yet still keep them in my DbContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your means of trying to create your own IMigrationsSqlGenerator was correct, and I've used that approach before to alter the SQL that is generated as part of a migration.

```cs
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseSqlServer();
                opt.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, SkipMigrator>();
            });
```

However, as of EF Core 5.0 it's now much easier to exclude specific tables from migrations using the `ExcludeFromMigrations()` method on a `TableBuilder`:

```cs
public class ReportingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable(nameof(Users), t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
    }
}
```

More info: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-efcore-5-0-rc1/#exclude-tables-from-migrations

Answer (score 1):

> If there a different/simpler way to tell migrations to skip tables yet still keep them in my DbContext?

Yes, but it requires a different approach.

Instead of using your current `DbContext` class for creating migrations, create a `SecondDbContext` class only for the very purpose of creating migrations. This new `SecondDbContext` class will hold the `DbSets<T>` that you want EF to do its migrations on.

Then simply specify the second context when calling `add-migration UpdateTable -c SecondDbContext` and then `update-database -c SecondDbContext`.